# Space-X Falcon-9 and Falcon Heavy fuel consumed for landing

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, falcon-heavy

The question is, how much fuel is used by each of above rockets for landing (in % of whole fuel of the rocket) as a function of three following components - payload, orbit and descend trajectory (land/barge I guess). Is there any official figures? One can sit down, watch the launch live on youtube and count number of engines fired and seconds they were left ignited. Its kinda may give the right order of magnitude. But do we have more precise numbers?

EDIT: Do they currently employ Merlin engines? If so, counting seconds of engine ignition is no good, since Merlins can throttle from 100% to 70% of thrust.